# Separate phones from tablets (htaccess or javascript or php)

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, mobile

Is there a valid method to efficiently separate mobile phones from tablets, to redirect phones to a mobile version a site, but not tablets?

My ideas :

**htaccess redirect** : Although I could find a way to redirect all mobile devices, I haven't managed to go further and split phones from tablets.

**User agent JS filter** : same problem.

**User agent + window.width** : works to some extent, but I obviously can't test every device and I don't want a landscape tablet to be considered as a phone and vice versa...

Is there a best practice for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what is considered best practices acording to google:

- Make a responsive website so you don't have to separate devices
- Serve different HTML for each device using the user-agent header
- Redirect to a mobile-specific site using the user-agent header

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/

Although I'd recommend a responsive site, you seem to be inclined to segregate phones. There are good libraries to do this:

https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

It is not a perfect solution because it is difficult to trace a line between a big phone and a small tablet (say a Galaxy Note and a Nexus 7)

Comment: I'm totally inclined to make a responsive website, but sometimes the client has its own views... thanks!